# TurboGears2 / ToscaWidgets - Buttons

Tags: button, turbogears2, toscawidgets

I am using TG2 and created a form with following buttons:

```
buttons = [SaveButton(),CancelButton()]
```

Now I would like to change a few things:

- Change the displayed name of the buttons (so from "Save Form" to something else)
- Change the redirect link from the CancelButton (default seems to point to /index/)

This is probably really easy to do, but I am having a tough time finding any information about this in the docs.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Ok, so I figured out how to change the label of a the buttons:

aka: SaveButton(value='Save User')

Is there some sort of list/index that tells me what other parameters I can give a button? Specifically the redirect link for a CancelButton?

Comment: ok. Apparently 'link' is another attribute that works. problem solved.

Comment: You should always try to read the source, if the docs don't suffice... Especially for ToscaWidgets 1, the docs are really unmaintained and broken, so the source might be your only chance to figure out what's possible.